# Access Python Row index

Tags: python, pandas, row

I am trying to access row index as a variable not as list nor anything else. 
I tried different methods without success, can anyone be in anyway to help. 
thanks,

```
ddo=df[(df.iloc[:,3]==4) & (df.iloc[:,5]==2) & (df.iloc[:,6]==2) & (df.iloc[:,15]>=0.02)]

starttime=ddo.iloc[0,1] 
starttimerow=ddo.index[ddo.iloc[0,1]==starttime]
```

the expected output to be list not an array

```
array([[103971, 104031, 104090, 104149, 104209, 104269, 104327, 104385,
        104445, 104503, 104562, 104621, 104680, 104737, 104797, 104856,
        104914, 104973, 105032, 105091, 105149, 105209, 105267, 105326,
        105384, 105443, 105502, 105561, 105620, 105679, 105738, 105796,
        105855, 105914, 105972, 106032, 106091, 106150, 106209, 106268,
        106326, 106385, 106444, 106502, 106562, 106621, 106680, 106739,
        106798, 106856, 106915, 106974, 107032, 107092, 107151, 107210,
        107269, 107328, 107386, 107445, 107505, 107565, 107627, 107688,
        107751, 107813, 107875, 107935, 107998, 108059, 108120]],
      dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Can you also tell what was the input?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, how is your expected output different from the output you posted?

Comment: What is `print (ddo.index)` ?

Comment: it is the array below.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these lines

```
enddwellrow=df.loc[(ddo.iloc[:,1]==end_dwell)&(ddo.iloc[:,3]==4)].reset_index()   

    enddwell_idx=enddwellrow['index'][0]
```